# Why dont my update resultset work

Tags: java, database-connection, sql-update, resultset

I got Update sql that doesn't work, and i can't seem to make it work. I have no idea where it goes wrong, I get i Nullpointer exception.

this is my KaldSQL class

```
public ResultSet opdatereOrdre(Connection con, int BestillingsID, int Modtager){

    ResultSet opdatereOrdre = null;

    try {
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE varebestillinger set BestillingsStatus=1, ModtagetAf ="+Modtager+" where BestillingsID="+BestillingsID);
        opdatereOrdre = stmt.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return opdatereOrdre;
}
```

this is my HentbestillingsordreHandler

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println(hentordregistrer.BestillingsID);
                        try {

                            con = ks.connectNow();
                            ResultSet rs = ks.opdatereOrdre(con, hentordregistrer.BestillingsID, 1);

                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }
                });
```

the error i get is

```
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:412)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1794)
    at KaldSQL.opdatereOrdre(KaldSQL.java:126)
    at HentbestillingsordreHandler$1.actionPerformed(HentbestillingsordreHandler.java:120)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Watch out about how do you use `opdatereOrdre` once it is returned from the method. If it fails for any reason you're returning a null reference. If you try to use it later you'll get a NPE.

Comment: To execute an update don't use `executeQuery`, use [`executeUpdate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()), and as your Stacktrace shows, you don't have an NPE, you have a `SQLException`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905607/can-not-issue-data-manipulation-statements-with-executequery

You're having exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like an NPE, it looks like you need to use executeUpdate instead of executeQuery. You might try this:

```
...
con.createStatement();
opdatereOrdre = stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE varebestillinger set BestillingsStatus=1, ModtagetAf ="+Modtager+" where    BestillingsID="+BestillingsID);
...
```

Comment: you should advise the person to use bound parameters, never concat them to SQL...

Comment: Perhaps. I would agree with you in cases where the parameterized type is more complex - like a date -- and you want JDBC to manage the type conversion. However, when using raw, parameterized JDBC with indexes, I believe you make the code more brittle by making it possible to get indices wrong.

Comment: even if you wouldn't do tests on the code - which you should - getting the param index wrong will fail immediately on first try, and it will fail on every time tried, consistently. With concatenation, the code *seems* to work, but with `--`, `"` or similar it can suddenly fail leading to nasty consequences. That's what I'd think is more brittle.

Comment: The subtle error will not fail at compile time or runtime: setInt(1, BestillingsID) and setInt(2, Modtager).

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly three useful methods for executing query using JDBC, here below is the explaination about all that methods and understanding that where to use that methods

```
1. boolean execute()
```

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which may be any kind of SQL statement.

```
2. ResultSet executeQuery()
```

Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

```
3 . int executeUpdate()
```

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.