# Running a native insert query in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-native-query

I am trying to run a simple insert query in spring boot but I am unable to do so.

Query:

```
@Modifying
    @Query(value = "insert into Local(userId,name,address,pin) VALUES (:userId,:name,:address,:pin)", nativeQuery = true)

    List < Local > insertattributes(@Param("userId")String userId,@Param("address") String address ,@Param("name")String name,@Param("pin") String pin);
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("insertattributes/{userId}/{name}/{address}/{pin}")
    @ResponseBody
    public List < Local > insertAttributes(@PathVariable String userId, @PathVariable String name, @PathVariable String address, @PathVariable String pin) {

        return localService.insertattributes(userId,name,address,pin);
    }
```

Error:

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
```

Comment: Your `insertattributes` method in repository should be `void`. It is inappropriate to expect `List<Local>` during insert

Comment: I want to cache the response.That is why I was trying to return a List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An insert statement doesn't return the inserted record. Since you're expecting a list to be returned `executeQuery()` is executed by Spring. What you want is the executiong of `executeUpdate()` which is only executed for void methods.

See also [Cannot issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905607/cannot-issue-data-manipulation-statements-with-executequery)

Comment: Is there a way to fetch a list?

Comment: I found the same issue with the update queries too.I understand what you are saying but is there a workaround so that I can get a list or an object?

Comment: The question here is what you actually want to do. Is there a need for excuting a native query for your insert? Why don't you create an instance of your `Local` class and call `repository.save()` in your JpaRepository? That would also return the saved record for you.

See also https://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/ for reference