# MySQL query returning false, but executing correctly

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I am working out of Google Apps Script and connecting to an external database using JDBC.

I have a user table and a contracts table, I have changed some of the values for privacy but this is my basic query. Basically I have a list of contract numbers that I want to loop over, and for each one, execute the query. The contracts table and the user table share a primary id, so I am just trying to update a value in the user table, where the users contract id equals the contract id of that contract number.

```
var contractNumbers = ["123","456","789"];
for (var a in contractNumbers) {
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();  
  var contractNum = contractNumbers[a];
  var query = "UPDATE user INNER JOIN contracts ON user.id_c = contracts.id SET user.quantity = '1' WHERE contracts.number = '" + contractNum + "'";
  var stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
  var result = stmt.execute();
}
```

This query is working and is changing the value correctly and accurately, however the result always returns false. Any idea what may be wrong with my query that it is working, but returning false? Or maybe a suggestion for a better way to execute this query?

Comment: just edited my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are entering datas and not getting datas the return is `false`
The doc says:

> Returns:
>       true if the first result is a ResultSet object; false if the first result is an update count or there is no result.

In your case it's an update and there is no result

Full documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#execute())

Comment: Thanks @jsmith! This explained it, however, executeQuery() threw an error, so I googled the error and found that I should be using executeUpdate() when manipulating data. I changed it to this and it worked perfectly. Thanks for pushing me in the right direction!

Comment: No problem glad it helped ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @JSmith above, I was pointed in the right direction. The proper execution is:

```
 var result = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Per - [Cannot issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905607/cannot-issue-data-manipulation-statements-with-executequery)